# How to move iTunes library from external drive to NAS without loosing playcounts etc

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, itunes, music

My Itunes library is on an external drive (L:\itl) while actual music files are on a different folder of the same drive (L:\music).

I tried to copy the ITL and music folder on my NAS (Mapped as network drive N so they now reside in N:\Itl and N:\Music).

When I start iTunes without the external drive it asks for a library location and I point to the .itl file on N drive.

Itunes starts, I see the songs, playlists and so on but when I try to play something it says that file could not be located.

I tried to change edit\preferences and in the advanced tab I set the new location of music files (N:\music) but I still have the file could not be located error.

How can I properly setup the library from NAS? I do not want to enable "Keep media organized" because I want to keep my folders organised in a different way.
Moreover I need to keep added, last played and so on because my smart playlists are heavily based on these data.

It seems that on MAC this operation is very easy but I use Windows 10.

Comment: It used to be very easy when iTunes used an xml file. With just the itl it's now a nasty job. If you can symlink the new location to the old one, you'll probably find that far easier. Refs: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293764/move-external-itunes-library-files-to-different-location-without-losing-metadata https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163594/itunes-moving-itunes-files-self-managed

Comment: @Tetsujin, for now I cheated as you suggested, the nas is now mapped to L, old L has a different letter and itunes works again.

Comment: I would feel rather 'cheap' to post that as an actual answer... but that might indeed be the future for iTunes moves :/